# Software configuration without using static fields

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection, configuration-files

I am working on a Java program using a configuration object filled from a configuration file (using apache commons config). The configuration object is currently referenced from a static field and several classes depend from it, however I have learned that using static fields is a bad practice and it's not healthy especially for testing. My alternative approach is to inject the config object to each of the classes depending from it. Is that a good alternative? Or should I have a more fine grained approach where I only pass the actual configuration parameters required by each class?

Comment: Have you considered using a singleton?  Maybe defining a singleton manager which acts as the controller to the instance of the config?

Comment: How many properties does each class need? Have you looked at the Spring `ConfigurationProperties` approach?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - singleton - with regards to expressed concerns like testability - is just extraordinary malign variant of static field.

Comment: @Michal So we're going to throw away usability and functionality for testability then?

Comment: You have `dependency-injection` as a tag; well, there are some good DI frameworks in Java (Dagger, Guice), maybe you should look this way

Comment: @MadProgrammer - this won't be necessary, it will suffice to store the mentioned configuration into non-static field in each class which needs to access it. This is preferably done using DI-style injection but even setter or constructor parameter would suffice. Having avoided the static field of which a singleton is really only a variant also helps to avoid number of other potential issues, for example MT-related, JEE deployment related and yes, regarding the testability too.

Comment: Even though I'm appreciating the DI-style at the current stage the project is not using any DI framework. @Michal got what I mean. My idea would be to pass the config object as a constructor parameter. What is making me unsure though, is the idea of passing around this object pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @DanTheMan - yeah, that's where a DI framework would come in. Without DI I would consider carefully whether to use setter methods or constructor parameters, I personally would go with former. Regarding the other part of the question, I would always pass/set/inject the whole configuration and not bother with extracting a subset.